# Why is this DIV shifted downwards?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a simple website using `DIV`-s, for some reason the `menu` *div* is shifted down about *200px*, whats causing this?

[Website Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90210205/Default.html)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxM7P/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="titlediv"><!--Title-->
    <a href="Default.html"><img src="res1/title500x100.png" class="pagelogo"/></a>
</div>

<div id="container"><!--Full Width Content-->
    <div id="menu"><!--Title-->
        <ul class="tablemenu">
            <li><a href="Default.html" id="link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Link5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="divider"><!--Black Divider-->
    </div>

    <div id="content"><!--Main Content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#titlediv{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
}

.pagelogo{
    max-height:100px;
}

#container{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#menu{
    width:250px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:orange;
    display:inline-block;
}

#menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
}

#menu a{
    font-size:40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-color:black;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:black;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
}

#menu a:hover{
    background-color:#999967;
}

#divider{
    width:5px;
    height:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;
}

#content{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Also I want the second row of `div`-s (*Menu* + *divider* + *content*) to be **centered** within the *blue* `#container` `div`, how do I do that?

Comment: You are using `id='link'` multiple times. `id`s need to be unique, you should change this to a `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu container is set to `display: inline-block`, which defaults to `vertical-align: bottom`. All you need is to add this:

```
#menu {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is old, but I can't figure it out: if `vertical-align` defaults to `bottom`, why doesn't the `#menu div` seem to align with anything? The top of it is somewhere in the middle of the rest of the content, and the bottom is way past. How is it aligning to the bottom? The bottom of what?

Comment: "How is it aligning to the bottom?" The bottom of the text in the `menu` div is aligning with the bottom of the `container` div. Changing the vertical alignment to `top` tells the text in the `menu` div to align with the top of the `container` div.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical shift in menu is caused by the `display: inline-block;` in the CSS for `#menu`.  If you need to use `inline-block` you can also add `vertical-align: top;` to fix it.

Comment: should i do this for all 3 DIVs on that row?

Comment: It doesn't matter currently, as there is a height set on those other divs and there is nothing taller than them. But it's best not to set heights on main elements like that, so in reality, you will probably find you need to set the vertical alignment on these also once they start to fill with content.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: inline-block` and use `float:left` on #menu and #divider.

To centre, restrict your #container so that it's the width you want, then use `margin:0px auto` (or use a new `div` with that margin property).

You may be able to get rid of #divider if you use the border or background properties on #menu, it depends on what you want that divider in there for.